# How to create bold UIFont

Tags: ios, uitableview, uifont

I am doing some word wrapping in my tableview as some of the values are so big they go off the edge of the screen.

However, the font and size and boldness dose not match the default settings of the table view and was hoping someone could help me fix that up.

This is what I am doing to set the fields:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = @"Go get some text for your cell.";
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you're using the version of Helvetica that is bundled in iOS, you can simply do:

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for that I will accept your answer once the time is over.. you wouldnt by chance know the default size of the font thats normally in tableview cells?

Comment: okay cheers.. for some reason 17 is still alot smaller than what come up in the cells I am not initializing.. sall good probably just my application.

Answer (score 62):

You can look into the `fontNamesForFamilyName:` method.

Specifically for Helvetica there are these families

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"]);
```

> ```
> "Helvetica-LightOblique",
> Helvetica,
> "Helvetica-Oblique",
> "Helvetica-BoldOblique",
> "Helvetica-Bold",
> "Helvetica-Light"
> ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. theTRON's isn't complete enough!

Comment: iOS9 is switching to SanFrancisco font style family.

Answer (score 28):

You have to ask for the font specifically, for example

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17.0]
```

Here is a list of available fonts: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6000-list-uifonts-available.html

Answer (score 16):

You would use:

```
+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

If you provided a custom font or are using a system-provided font, you'd use the bold typeface as the name of the font:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17];
```