# How to make some text of UIButton BOLD

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to set my UIButton title to === Don`t have an account? **Sign Up**

How to make some text Bold.

```
    UIButton *signUpButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 270, 240, 40)];
    [signUpButton setTitle:@"Don`t have an account? Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [signUpButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    signUpButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [signUpButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [signUpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signUpAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:signUpButton];
```

Not able to implement attributed strings ..

Comment: hi please using attributed string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create bold UIFont](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888328/how-to-create-bold-uifont)

Comment: Can you please provide the code. Above is what i am doing right now .

Comment: I tried but not able to implement attributed string @ilesh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set here your button text like this ...

```
[yourbutton setAttributedTitle:[self UnderLineTextString:strString]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Please try this function ...

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString *)UnderLineTextString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];

    [titleString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];// set your text lenght..

    return titleString;
}
```