# Making specific words in a title label bold in a UIButton in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a beginner at swift and I've found that [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959027/bold-part-of-a-uibutton-title-label) and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316976/how-to-make-some-text-of-uibutton-bold/33317139) has not helped me with my case, most probably because I've coded it differently to them (ie Swift, not Obc).

```swift
    private let createAccountButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("dont have an account? sign up!", for: .normal) //line 4
        return button
```

I would like the text "sign up!" in line 4 to be formatted in bold but haven't found anything online that can support it with the current way I've coded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use button `setAttributedTitle` property for set attributed text.

First, create attributed text.

Here, I created a string extension for bold attributed text. Which return attributed text and set this attributed text to button.

```
extension String {
    /// Return attributed string
    /// - Parameter text: String text for bold text.
    func getAttributedBoldText(text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue])
        if let range = self.range(of: text) {
            let startIndex = self.distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            let range = NSMakeRange(startIndex, text.count)
            attributedString.addAttributes([.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)], range: range)
        }
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
private let createAccountButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setAttributedTitle("dont have an account? sign up!".getAttributedBoldText(text: "sign up!"), for: .normal) // Here
    return button
}()
```

Note: Modify the extension attributed function as per your layout.